# pass data from intent to an other intent

Tags: android

I have two `Intent`s and two `Activity`s.

I have in the first `Intent` an `EditText`.

I want to use the text in the `EditText` in the second intent and pass to the second intent

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(mycurentActivity.this, secondActivity.class);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your looking for [Intent#putExtra(String, String).](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Here is an example:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(mycurentActivity.this, secondActivity.class);
myIntent.putExtra("key", myEditText.Text.toString();
startActivity(myIntent);
```

When your receiving the Intent you can extract it again:

```
String text = myIntent.getStringExtra("key");
```

(http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getStringExtra(java.lang.String))

Comment: I put the code like you write it, then Eclipse asks me to create a local Variable Intent and initialize it to null;
then I run the code and I get an empty screen
Thanks in advance.
Best regrads

Comment: You should create a local variable int. Show please the code where you did that.

Comment: Is there no way to pass objects? This way is really devious

Answer (score 0):

First Activity

```
 Intent myIntent = new Intent(rechercheCP.this, XMLParsing.class);
                    myIntent.putExtra("key", autoComplete.getText().toString());
                    startActivity(myIntent);
```

Second Activity

```
TextView a;
String text = myIntent.getStringExtra("key");
a = new TextView(this);
    a.setText(text);
    layout.addView(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

in the First activity

```
//...
final static int EDIT=0;
//...(action trigger)
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Intent intent;
    intent = new Intent().setClass(mycurentActivity.this, secondActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, EDIT);
}
//...
```

and later in the First activity

```
//...
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    switch(requestCode){
        case EDIT:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            String text = data.getStringExtra("key");
            //do whatever with the text...
        }else if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
        }
    break;
    }
}
//...
```

and second activity

```
//...
Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(secondActivity.this, mycurentActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("key", myEditText.getText().toString);
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();
//...
```