# What may prevent the UI in android to be updated on time?

Tags: android

I'm developing an Android app that has to update it's UI depending on receiving and processing some server responses, I'm using `runOnUiThread` for that. I have like five activities in that app, all is working very well but one requires me to **relaunch** the Activity(like going to another one and then returning to it) or **interacting with it** in order to that update takes place, and that is the way i'm using with all the Activities including the infected one:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                 response_received(response);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                 e.printStackTrace(); // never catch any Exceptions
                }
            }
        });

private static void response_received(JSONObject response) throws Exception{

try {
     int volume_setted = response.getInt(volume);
     Normal_Activity.volume_value.setText(String.valueOf(volume_setted)); // the Volume TextView updated efficiently
     Infected_Activity.volume_value.setText(String.valueOf(volume_setted)); // has the problem mentioned above
    } catch (JSONException ex) {
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure the problem is not in the TextView as all the Activity UI has this problem but i just posted an example.

Comment: please add logcat logs, so then it's easy to figure out

Comment: @ChaturaDilanPerera there is nothing about that in the Logcat, as I mentioned above the Exception is never thrown and when i tried to print a log message after the last line to make sure it's already reached, the message printed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Do not directly set values in a Activity from another Activity. If you want to pass data to Another activity always use Intents. check the below link

[pass data from intent to an other intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5492648/pass-data-from-intent-to-an-other-intent)

If you want to start another activity and get result back check the below link

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html