# How can I get the ID's of user who are login with my apps?

Tags: java, android

How can I get the ID's of user who are login with my apps?

I have two activity. The first one is login activity and second one is registration activity. I am also using JSON. If a user is successfully registered, then it creates an ID. I need that ID at my login page.

Register.java

```
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         int success;
         String firstname = first.getText().toString();
         String lastname = last.getText().toString();
         String emailaddress = emailet.getText().toString();
         String username = user.getText().toString();
         String password= passet.getText().toString();
         try {
              List params = new ArrayList();
              params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("first_name", firstname));
              params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("last_name", lastname));
              params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_email", emailaddress));
              params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_name", username));
              params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_pass", password));
              
              Log.d("request!", "starting");
              JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);
              Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());
              success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
              if (success == 1) {
                  Log.d("User Created!", json.toString());   
       ;
              
                  
                  
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), json.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  
                  finish();
                  return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
              }else{
                  Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                  return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                  
              }
              
              
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
         
        return null;
    }
```

Login.java

```
protected String doInBackground(String...args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int success;
        String username = user.getText().toString();
        String password = pass.getText().toString();
        try {
            List params = new ArrayList();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_email", username));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_pass", password) );
            Log.d("request!", "starting");
            JSONObject json = jsonParse.makeHttpRequest(LOGIN_URL, "GET", params);
              Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

            
              success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
              if (success == 1) {
                  Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());
               
                  return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
              }else{
                  Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                  return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);      
              }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
          
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: share what you have tried. then if you got stucked 

with some exact issue, we will help you. Refer this link for asking proper questions 
http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: post your code or you will get minuses)

Comment: Pass it from login activity to login page. Refer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5492648/pass-data-from-intent-to-an-other-intent

Comment: http://startandroid.ru/en/lessons/complete-list/241-lesson-28-extras-passing-data-using-intent.html, look this you will get a better idea

Comment: Can you also post the response??

Answer (score 0):

Your need to first store that Id some where in the database then at the time of login you need to pass that id with the username and password

Comment: can u post one example like my above problem?I m so much confuse.how i will store and how can i fetch?

Comment: which database you are using.? mssql or mysql?

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your Session Manager.

```
public static void saveSession_userid(SharedPreferences prefs,String value) {
    SessionManager.savePreference(prefs, USERID, value);
}

public static String get_session_userid(SharedPreferences prefs) {
    return prefs.getString(USERID, "");
}
```

This in your Login Asynctask onPostExecute()

```
if (login_result.equals("sucess")) {
id = jsonObject.getString("userId");
SessionManager.saveSession_userid(prefs, id);
```

and declare this:

```
SharedPreferences prefs;
prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```